# Converter category plugin not included in log4j2 plugins dat file in Jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j2

First a bit of background of what I'm trying to do. My employer is moving from Windows servers, using C#, to Java on Linux to migrate to AWS. This particular issue came up trying to create a Log Appender to push logs to AWS CloudWatch. I'm still fairly new to Java, so please bear with me :) I'm programming using IntelliJ-IDEA 15.0.2 Windows

I found an existing Log Appender that a Mihailo Despotovic had created. [Github Link](https://github.com/Virtual-Instruments/cloudwatch-log4j-appender)

I did a few modifications to make it more configurable for usage of credential Profile, Log Group/Stream, etc.

Now to the issues I have experienced and hopefully someone can guide me to a possible solution.

> Try #1

I did this on a AWS instance. My Chef recipe created the log4j2.xml file in the same folder as the Jar file. Configurations were assigned with Custom JSON from the Stack. The call of the Jar file had -Dlog4j.configurationfile point to the path/log4j2.xml. As soon getLogger() is called, a flood of **ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [XXXX]** where XXXX was different layout options. It then said it couldn't find a log4j2 configuration file and that default would be used, then followed with the exact same flow of **ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized ...**

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration packages="com.something.something">
    <Appenders>
        <CloudWatchLogAppender name="CloudWatchLogAppender"
                           awsLogGroupName="log group name"
                           awsLogStreamName="log stream name"
                           awsCredentialProfile="credential profile name"
                           queueDepth="50000"
                           drainLimit="256"
                           flushPeriod="5"
                           >
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg" />
        </CloudWatchLogAppender>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="CloudWatchLogAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

> Try #2

This time, from IDEA, I wanted to include log4j2.xml into the Jar, without worrying about the dynamic configuration settings. XML file was placed in src/main/resources

This created following output when getLogger() is called:

```
ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class com.something.something.CloudWatchLogAppender for element CloudWatchLogAppender.
ERROR Null object returned for CloudWatchLogAppender in Appenders.
ERROR Unable to locate appender "CloudWatchLogAppender" for logger config "root"
```

> Try #3

Next I wanted to try and set the configuration programmatically in Java. The log4j docs was a bit confusing to me, but I stumbled over this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-743

And changed to use my Custom Log Appender:

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger rootLogger = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) LogManager.getRootLogger();
PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.createLayout("%msg", null, null, null, null, false, true, null, null);
CloudWatchLogAppender appender = new CloudWatchLogAppender("CloudWatchLogAppender",
                    logGroupName,
                    logStreamName,
                    null,
                    queueDepth,
                    drainLimit,
                    flushPeriod,
                    layout);
appender.start();
rootLogger.getContext().getConfiguration().addLoggerAppender(rootLogger, appender);
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(com.something.something.App.class);
```

I had to include following, to change the default Level.ERROR to something else (will handle the "levels" by configuration):

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
loggerConfig.setLevel(Level.ALL);
ctx.updateLoggers();
```

This works like a charm when running from IDEA. Anything that is logged goes to AWS CloudWatch as expected.

I then build it into a Jar (maven project, also tried in gradle), run it and the same flood of **ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [XXXX]** happened.

The Log Appender still log to AWS CloudWatch, but instead of the actual log message, it just sent the pattern layout of **%msg**

I then used remote debugging to see if I could drill down into log4j2 and find the difference between running it from IDEA vs Jar. That is where I found out that when running from IDEA, it reference the maven repository log4j2-core 2.5 Jar to get the **Log4j2Plugins.dat** and find the plugin category default, called **converter**. But when running from Jar, it uses the META-INF/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/Log4j2Plugins.dat that was included by maven into the Jar, and it only have "root" category and a reference to my Custom Log Appender. This means that log4j2 is not able to find the expected default category of **converter**, which creates the flood of layout errors.

I even tried to extract the **Log4j2Plugins.dat** file out of the repository core Jar file and include in the project under the same path. It is ignored when building the Jar.

How will I be able to get past that issue and have maven include the correct **Log4j2Plugins.dat** file? Or any other possible solution?

**EDITED**

Hack that works with Try #3:

I extracted Log4j2Plugins.dat from the log4j2 core jar repository file and included in my Chef Cookbook. Have the recipe copy the file into the correct folder structure and then use "jar -uf" to update my jar file via the recipe.